# Сообщение: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Вылезает сообщение при попытке сборки проекта.

Появилось после обновления `Gradle` до версии`gradle:3.3.0`:

> WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and
>   has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'. It
>   will be removed at the end of 2019. For more information, see
>   https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance. To
>   determine what is calling variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks(), use
>   -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace. 
>   Affected Modules: app

Ответов на EN.SO кроме как просто закоментить `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` и забыть - не нашел.
Коментить не вариант, так как я использую эту фабрику.

Пытался тщетно понять о чем речь читая инфу которую гугл дает по [ссылке](https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance). (Интересно, только у меня сложилось впечатление что они писали эту инфу для своих разработчиков. Которые уже это по 100 раз делали?!).

Где метод `variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()`, который нужно поменять, не могу найти.

---

UPD:
В той же связке вылезли еще 6 предупреждений. Но так как это все из-за обновления `Gradle`, то решил их то-же сюда добавить. Как говорится "7 бед - один ответ":

> API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'variant.getAssembleProvider()'.
>   API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been
>    replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
>   API 'variantOutput.getProcessManifest()' is obsolete and has been replaced
>    with 'variantOutput.getProcessManifestProvider()'.
>   API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>    'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
>   API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>    'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
>   API 'variant.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced
>    with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'.

---

Подскажите, как все же сделать рекомендуемые Гуглом изменения и не потерять кусок кода который нужен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно связаться с авторами плагинов, которые генерят эти предупреждения, и сообщить им о небоходимости отрефакторить код. Вот, например, [так сообщили нам](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119771/gradle-6-0-deprecated-message-with-ivyartifactrepository-layoutstring-closure).

Comment: Резонно. А как вылавливать плагины? Получается только поштучно отключать и смотреть что пропало?

Comment: влючить stack trace и смотреть откуда warning–и идут.